# How can I call a method prior to reading an active record object's attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For each attribute of a model, I want to be able to call a method prior to returning the result of said attribute.

For instance, consider model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def some_attribute
    # modify return result
  end
end

User.new.some_attribute # returns modified result
```

I want to be able to call this `some_attribute` method for every attribute that the model has.

Comment: I am sorry but your question is unclear to me. You want to call the `some_attribute` and it should return different, modified attributes on each call? In your example, you define a `some_attribute` getter method but a few lines alter you call a `some_attribute=` setter method - how are they connected? Can you please elaborate and explain what you actually try to achieve? What problem do you try to solve? Why do you need to call a method before returning the actually attributes value?

Comment: do you want to get all available attributes (table columns) for user with key-values?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [`read_attribute`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read.html#method-i-read_attribute) method. *Since you don't give any examples of how you are going to use it might or might not be the proper way.*

```
def some_attribute
  data = read_attribute[:some_attribute]
  # Then do something and return what you want
  # return data
end
```

Comment: Good call out on how this answer depending on how it is used might not be the proper way!